# Get first column from certain point in sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get a list of rows from within a column after a cell with text has been found. So in my example i would like all the names in the first column after the "Name" cell

[image]

I currently have the following but have no idea what i am doing as this is the first time using google scripts

```
function getNames(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(mastersPoolID);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var col = data[0].findIndex((name) => name === 'Name') + 1;
  
  Logger.log(col);

  return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(col))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Comment: Don't merge cells in Google Sheets. Maintaining the data structure is more important than appearance.

Comment: are you saying dont do this? `getDataRange().getValues()`

Comment: Why did you select `data[0]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This do the work:

```
function getNames(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(mastersPoolID);
  var data = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues().flat().filter(a => a != '');
  return  data.slice(data.indexOf('Name') + 1);
}
```

Explanation:

1. We only need the first column, so in order to make things simpler we will grab only Column A.
2. Array.prototype.flat flattens the Array returned by `getValues()`
3. Array.prototype.filter removes all elements that doesn't meet the condition, in this all the empty strings.
4. Array.prototype.indexOf finds the positio of an element
5. Array.prototype.slice get the elements from a position

```js
var AA = [[''],[''],['Name'], [''],['John'],[''],['Mary']];
var data = AA.flat().filter(a => a != '');
console.log( data.slice(data.indexOf('Name') + 1));
```